# what is the intuitive explanation of the truth of the statement if 0=1, then 1=2?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the statement
if 0=1, then 1=2
This statement is weird but since the hypothesis (if 0=1) is false, then according to propositional logic the entire statement is true, although the conclusion (then 1=2) is false. I just cannot understand how can we consider the entire statement to be true even though our conclusion is wrong. Can you provide another examples where such situation is easy to grasp? Maybe I can get it with concrete examples.

Comment: $P\implies Q$ is equivalent to $\neg Q \implies \neg P$, so if you have both the hypothesis and conclusion as false, $\neg Q\implies \neg P$ is satisfied, hence by equivalence of the statements, $P\implies Q$ is satisfied.

Comment: Note that in this specific case we arguably don't even need to appeal to the technicalities of material implication. The claim "$\forall a,b[a=b\implies a+1=b+1]$" should be pretty unproblematic, and applying this to $0=1$ immediately gives $1=2$, so "$0=1\implies 1=2$" should (I would argue) be unproblematic.

Comment: Propositional logic offers a simplifird model of natural language based on so-called truth-functional definition of logical connectives. According to this definition, an "if...,then..." statement is considered false when the antecedent is false.

Comment: Thus, **every** example with false antecedent will produce the same effetti.

Comment: For intuition it is helpful to think of p ⟹ q, as ¬ p ∨ q, so 1 = 0 ⟹ 1 = 2 becomes 1 ≠ 0 ∨ 1 = 2, which is hopefully a fairly intuitive statement- in regards to truth values

Comment: read up on the principle of explosion. a contradiction implies anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is really expanding on Noah Schweber's comment.)

We have a true rule of arithmetic, that if $a = b$ then $a+1 = b+1$. (This follows in any system where equal things may be substituted for each other.)

So if $0 = 1$, then $0+1 = 1+1$, so $1 = 2$. You applied a perfectly valid transformation ("add $1$ to both sides") to an input, validly obtaining an output. The fact that the input was nonsense means the output was nonsense, but that doesn't make the *transformation* bad.

---

An implication $A \to B$ can be thought of as a *process* that takes an $A$ and returns a $B$. The implication "$0 = 1 \to 1 = 2$" is a *process* that takes a proof that $0 = 1$, transforms it (e.g. by appending the line "you can add $1$ to both sides of an equality"), and outputs a proof that $1 = 2$. The *process* is valid, even though you can never actually execute it validly because you will never be able to provide it with a valid input (i.e. a proof that $0 = 1$).

Answer (score 4):

We never satisfy the hypothisis thus we can write whatever we want as a conclusion. Such a statment is called a "vacuous truth."

As for more concrete examples:
If the pigs fly, then blue is brown.
If Toronto is in Germany, then 1=2.

Comment: Ex falso quodlibet

Answer (score 2):

Here's an analogy that might be useful if you have any coding experience. If you have a conditional statement "if $P$ then $Q$," the compiler checks to see if $P$ is true before proceeding. If it is not, the compiler moves on without executing $Q.$ So the statement executes without an error.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot understand how can we consider the entire ‘if-then’ statement to be true even though its conclusion is false.

1. Notice that a conditional $$A\to B\tag1$$ and its consequent $$B\tag2$$ have different truth values *only* when $A$ and $B$ are both false. So, essentially, you are asking **why sentences $(1)$ and $(2)$ aren't just equivalent to each other.** But why should they be? After all, for example, the truth of $$A \land B$$ is determined by considering the truths of *both* $A$ and $B$ rather than the truth of just $B.$ Now, since sentence $(1)$ is logically equivalent to $$\lnot A\lor B$$ (they have the same truth table), it certainly can be true when $B$ is false.
2. A more satisfying and illuminating explanation of your discomfort is that because we commonly frame conditional statements as

   - if *premise*/*condition*, then *conclusion*/***implication***

   referring to an “implication” variously as the entire conditional $(1)$ as well as just its consequent $(2)$ (!), we tend to carelessly forget that they aren't actually equivalent to each other.

Comment: Then what truth are we asserting when saying ''if A, then B". In other words, if the truth of the conditional statement is not the same as the truth of its conclusion, then what truth am I asserting when I refer to the truth of the conditional statement? Sir, I understand that you said that the truth of the conditional statement is determined by both the hypothesis and the conclusion, then does this mean that truth of the conditional statement is an assertion of the logical coherence between the hypothesis and the conclusion?

Comment: @ManifestedPotential Yes, exactly. Also: [Understanding implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4772811/21813)

Answer (score 1):

The word "if" means something different in mathematical English than it means in ordinary English. In mathematical English, the word "if" is an abbreviation for a particular statement involving the words "not" and "or."

Specifically, when a mathematician writes a sentence like

> if *p*, then *q*,

then what they are **actually** saying is that

> either it's false that *p*, or it's true that *q*.

So, when a mathematician writes the sentence "if $0 = 1$, then $1 = 2$," then what the mathematician is actually claiming is:

> either it's false that $0 = 1$, or it's true that $1 = 2$.

This claim is, of course, true.

Answer (score 0):

We have the tautology: $ A \implies [\neg A \implies B]~$ (the principle of vacuous truth)

[image]

Source: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html

In your case, $A ~\equiv~ 0\neq 1$ and $B ~\equiv~ 1=2$:

$~~~~~~0\neq 1 \implies [0=1 \implies 1=2]$

When $A$ is true (lines 1 and 2 of the truth table), the implication of $\neg A \implies B$ will be true regardless of the truth value of $B$. In that case, we cannot use this result to infer anything about the truth value of $B$.

Using a form of natural deduction we can prove this tautology as follows (screenshot from my proof checker):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers here that address the technical content of your question. I want to add some words about the psychological content.

When you use an implication like $A \implies B$ in ordinary English or mathematical discourse you usually intend to express some kind of *causality*. Psychologically, you are saying that the truth of $A$ somehow causes or forces $B$ to be true. That's what the argument "proving" the implication demonstrates. When $A$ is false it tells you nothing about $B$.

Your problem arises when you try to define the meaning of the implication
"$A \implies B$" formally. The usual way to do that is with truth tables, which leads to the true implication

> The moon is made of green cheese $\implies$ I am the King of England.

I'm not the King of England, but the *implication* is correct.

In general terms, if $A$ is false then $A \implies B$ is true.

That definition of implication confuses many students. It's introduced to make everyday logic more formal and mathematical, but  it's very rarely relevant when beginners construct real mathematical proofs. I think it's not a good way to introduce logic and proof.

Logicians and philosophers struggle with it too, at a formal level. See https://www.britannica.com/topic/implication .